# Amazon Pay API-v2 Sandbox simulation not redirecting to checkoutCancelUrl

Tags: angular, amazon-pay

I have integrated **Amazon Pay API -v2 button** in my website. While using Sandbox simulation **"Visa ending in 3064"** with **"BuyerCanceled reason code"** Amazon hosted page is redirecting me to "checkoutResultReturnUrl" instead of "checkoutCancelUrl" even though providing "checkoutcancelUrl".

**webCheckoutDetails: after using get checkout session API**

```
{
    "checkoutReviewReturnUrl": "https://www.example.com:4200/checkout/review",
    "checkoutResultReturnUrl": "https://www.example.com:4200/checkout/success",
    "amazonPayRedirectUrl": "https://apay-us.amazon.com/checkout/processing?amazonCheckoutSessionId=bc1b9372-53ed-ec9eefc5188d",
    "authorizeResultReturnUrl": null,
    "checkoutCancelUrl": "https://www.example.com:4200/checkout/cancel"
}
```

can anyone explain why it it happening?

Comment: Can you share a checkout session id?